# unique constraint with all null values or all unique values

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Here is the sample table with 3 columns

```
(UNIQUE_VALUE, UNIQUE_VALUE1, UNIQUE_GROUP_ID)
```

I want below records can be allowed:

```
(NULL, NULL, NULL)
(NULL, NULL, NULL)
or

(3, 5, 7)
(4, 123, 7)
```

but it has to give error when input is like below.

```
(3, 5, 7)
(3, 5, 7)
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the error you are getting and post your table definition as wel

Comment: What about (3, 5, null) or (null, null, 7) are they to be allowed?

Comment: @Tony yes it should allow

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can allow duplicate `NULL` values by just using a `UNIQUE` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE sample (
  unique_value  NUMBER,
  unique_value1 NUMBER,
  unique_group_id NUMBER,
  CONSTRAINT sample__v__v1__gid__u UNIQUE( unique_value, unique_value1, unique_group_id )
);
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO sample
SELECT null, null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT null, null, null FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT    3,    5,    7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT    4,  123,    7 FROM DUAL;
```

Will insert 4 rows; but then trying to do:

```
INSERT INTO sample VALUES ( 3, 5, 7 );
```

Will raise the exception `ORA-0001: unique constraint (TEST.sample__v__v1__gid__u) violated`